# Merge if non duplicates

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two data frames (df1 and df2) based on two KEY (KEY1, and KEY2). However in df1, KEY1 is not unique. I want to merge df1 and df2 if KEY1 is unique. I generated a count variable which counts the number of occurence of KEY1, hence I want to merge df1 and df2 only if count equals 1.

Here is an example data frame:

```
df1$KEY1 <- as.data.frame(c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d"))
df1$count <- as.data.frame(c("2", "2", "1", "1", "1"))
```

```
df2$KEY2 <- as.data.frame(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
df2$value <- as.data.frame(c("85", "25", "581", "12", "4"))
```

My question is: how to perform the merge only if count equals 1?

```r
df1 <- if(count==1,merge(df1, df2, by.x=KEY1, by.y=KEY2, all.x=TRUE), ?)
```

My goal is to get this:

```
df1$KEY1 <- as.data.frame(c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d"))
df1$count <- as.data.frame(c("2", "2", "1", "1", "1"))
df1$value <- as.data.frame(c("NA", "NA", "25", "581", "12"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a join and change the values to `NA` if `count` is not 1.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('KEY1' = 'KEY2')) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, count != 1, NA))

#  KEY1 count value
#1    a     2  <NA>
#2    a     2  <NA>
#3    b     1    25
#4    c     1   581
#5    d     1    12
```

Similarly, in base R -

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'KEY1', by.y = 'KEY2') |>
  transform(value = replace(value, count != 1, NA))
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(KEY1 = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                 count = c("2", "2", "1", "1", "1"))
df2 <- data.frame(KEY2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                  value = c("85", "25", "581", "12", "4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using base, what you are looking for is the `incomparables` argument in `merge`. Values of the key included in it aren't mathched

```
tab <- table(df1$KEY1)
tab
merge(df1, df2, by.x="KEY1", by.y="KEY2", all.x=TRUE, 
    incomparables = names(tab)[tab>1])
```

The output is:

```
  KEY1 count value
1    a     2  <NA>
2    a     2  <NA>
3    b     1    25
4    c     1   581
5    d     1    12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    value = if_else(count == "1" & KEY1 %in% df2$KEY2, 
                    tibble::deframe(df2)[KEY1], 
                    NA_character_)
    )
```

which returns

```r
  KEY1 count value
1    a     2  <NA>
2    a     2  <NA>
3    b     1    25
4    c     1   581
5    d     1    12
```

Or the same as **base R**:

```r
transform(
  df1, 
  value = ifelse(df1$count == 1, 
                 `names<-`(df2$value, df2$KEY2)[df1$KEY1], 
                 NA_character_)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, value := NA^(count != 1) * value, on = .(KEY1 = KEY2)]
```

-output

```
> df1
   KEY1 count value
1:    a     2    NA
2:    a     2    NA
3:    b     1    25
4:    c     1   581
5:    d     1    12
```

NOTE: The numeric columns are created as `character`.  Assuming they are of `class` `numeric`, do a join `on` by `KEY` columns and assign the `value` to 'df1' after converting to `NA` based on 'count' column values

Comment: I was today years old when I learned that `NA^0` returns `1` and `NA^1` returns `NA`. This kind of `NA` handling is mind blowing. I can't upvote twice.

Comment: It is hacky way.  I don't know how long this behavior exist though (until some new R version decides to change it)